# Resharper is surrounding NUnit [SetUp] with regions upon Code Cleanup

Tags: c#, resharper

On Ctrl+E, C (Code Cleanup) ReSharper is surrounding the [SetUp] method with a region.

Anybody know how I can make that stop?  I don't like regions and I don't want them in any of my code.  It's slowing me down deleting them all the time.  I'm not going to stop using Code Cleanup because it's just too ace, but this aspect is annoying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go into resharper options ->type members layout.
Untick the use defaults layout and you will see the default layout in there.
You can look for the Nunit text you wish to remove and edit it out.
Apply it and your done.

Comment: Excellent tip. I added a couple of extra lines for the other NUnit attributes ... <HasAttribute CLRName="NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureSetUpAttribute" Inherit="true"/> <HasAttribute CLRName="NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureTearDownAttribute" Inherit="true"/>